# How to pick a file from default location and not by hard coding?

Tags: c#

I want to pick my XHTML dtd file from a default location like the bin folder ( where exe file of project resides) and not by hard coding it by giving the exact path of the file like C:\temp\xhtml1.dtd. My code is in C#.
Can anyone help how to do it?

Comment: (re comment) - if you are using uri, why give an example in the question that uses a file path? What is the *actual* setup here? Is it a web app? A ClickOnce app? What?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the application-base:

```
string path = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
            "foo.dtd");
```

Comment: I am using Uri and not string so what would be the syntax for that?

Comment: If you Uri is like this Uri u = new Uri("dtds/foo.dtd") the you can replace "foo.dtd" string in @Marc's answer with u.ToString().

Note: you should use relative Uri as AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase will return absolute path.

Comment: Sorry, using u.ToString() as I put in last comment will give funny string like C:\temp\test\bin\dtds/foo.dtd

you should try Path.Combind(Appdomain.....,

string.Join(@"\",u.Segments))

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want?

```
string xhtml = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"xhtml1.dtd";
```

Comment: That will give the working directory, which can be different (and which can change at runtime)

Comment: i am not using string but uri. How would i ab able to do same thing for uri?